# Как будет более грамотно в стиле psr написать

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, подскажите как лучше будет в плане psr, да и в целом ООП, чтобы более был читаемый код - передавать параметры с ajax в php.
Вот к примеру я получил post-параметры с ajax: deleteName,deleteEmail.

```
public function __construct()
    {

        $this->name=strip_tags($_POST["deleteName"]);
        $this->email=strip_tags($_POST["deleteEmail"]);
   }
```

Или:

```
public function __construct($name,$email)
    {
      $this->name = $name;
      $this->email = $email;
    }

//И потом:
    new Test(strip_tags($_POST["deleteName"]),strip_tags($_POST["deleteEmail"]);
```

И уже потом с этими переменными в методах взаимодействую

Или может по-другому как-то. Или вообще не имеет разницы?

Comment: PSR тут не при чём вообще, это рекомендации по стилю кода, но не логики, можно каждый из ваших примеров под psr сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от того, чем именно занимается этот класс. Парсингом, или обработкой. Вполне вероятно, что правильным будет такой вариант

```
class MyClass {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->name = $this->getParam("deleteName");
    $this->email = $this->getParam("deleteEmail");
   }

  private function getParam($name) {
    return strip_tags($_POST[$name]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Соответствует ли PSR переменная $AName ?

Answer (score 0):

Разница лишь в удобстве поддержки кода

Исходя из данных примеров я бы сделал так:

```
public function __construct($name,$email)
{
  $this->name = strip_tags($name);
  $this->email = strip_tags($email);
}

new Test($_POST["deleteName"],$_POST["deleteEmail"]);
```